# Waiting for some function complete in android

Tags: android

in my android app(media player), i'm scanning all media files in `loadingActivity.kt` file. and then starting `mainActivity.kt`. my code is

```
scanSongs()
intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

and my `scanSongs()` function is

```
private fun scanSongs() {
        val songsJob = async {
            val songsFinder = SongsLoader(contentResolver)
            songsFinder.load()
            songsFinder.getAllSongs()
        }
        launch {
            allSongsList = songsJob.await()
            allSongsList?.sortBy { it.getTitle() }
        }
    }
```

but before scan complete it is opening `mainActivity` . and showing empty list . how can i waiting for complete `scanSong()` , before open `mainActivity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the MainActivity when you have the allSongsList:

```
private fun scanSongs() {
        val songsJob = async {
            val songsFinder = SongsLoader(contentResolver)
            songsFinder.load()
            songsFinder.getAllSongs()
        }
        launch {
            allSongsList = songsJob.await()
            allSongsList?.sortBy { it.getTitle() }
            intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to check a condition before start mainactivity.kt that

song list is null or not

Comment: what if it is null ?